# Project Euler 5, answer I got is only half, why?

Tags: java

I am working on Project Euler number 5:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

However, the answer I keep getting, 116396280, is only half of the actual answer. Where am I going wrong? Why am I getting only half of the answer? This is in java by the way.

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long number=2520;//smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1-10
        long x;//for loop counter
        for (x=19;x>10;x-=2){
            if (x!=15){//its factors 5 and 3 have already been counted
                number*=x;//multiplies new prime numbers
            }
        }
       System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should quote the question rather than expect people to go over to Project Euler and find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By only walking through the odd numbers, you are missing out on 16, whose factorization is 2<sup>4</sup> Your answer only contains 2<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: Generally speaking, your code isn't much better than simply hard-coding the solution. Not to be rude, but I really suggest you rethink the solution from scratch.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not offended. I tried doing that but wasn't able to figure it out, I don't pretend to know too much right now, and so am turning you the kind users of stackoverflow for help.

Comment: Try considering the actual mathematical definition of the problem, and write an algorithm to implement the general case of it.